# Is "continue" the Pythonic way to escape from a try catch block?

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and thought of doing to simple django application to learn more about it, In one of the places in code I  had to  pick `locationName` and getting elements that matched same id as `locationName` in a table. When I started wondering is `continue` the most pythonic way to escape a for-loop?

Code in question is given below :

```
for locationName in locationGroup:
    idRef = locationName.id
    try:
        element = location.objects.order_by('-id').filter(name__id=idRef)[0]
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

Comment: Can't get more pythonic than using a keyword the way it's intended to..

Comment: Do you want to "escape" from the `try`/`catch` block (`pass`) or from the current loop iteration (`continue`) or from the entire loop (`break`)?

Comment: @user558061 escape from entire loop and go to next iteration

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was reading around and saw some articles about python not getting ternary operator for quite sometime as it wasn't _pythonic_ enough. That got me wondering about "continue" or any other  code-construct inherited from "C" .

Comment: @Shashank Well the language evolves - personally I consider the ternary operator as implemented in python quite pythonic and certainly much better than the old way abusing `or`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there's some code you don't want getting executed after the except clause, `continue` is perfectly valid, otherwise some might find `pass` more suitable.

```
for x in range(y):
    try:
        do_something()
    except SomeException:
        continue
    # The following line will not get executed for the current x value if a SomeException is raised
    do_another_thing() 

for x in range(y):
    try:
        do_something()
    except SomeException:
        pass
    # The following line will get executed regardless of whether SomeException is thrown or not
    do_another_thing()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (if we're answering the question in the title and not the one in the description).  `continue` is for breaking out of the current loop iteration and begin with the next iteration.  If you want to just escape out of the `try`/`except` block, `pass` is the correct keyword if you're not doing anything inside the `try` or `except` block.

To answer your (OP's) question, "Is “continue” the Pythonic way to escape from a try catch block?", then no, `pass` is the correct way if you're not doing anything in the block.

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what the `continue`/`break` keywords are for, so yes, that's the simplest and most pythonic way of doing it.

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
try:
    element = location.objects.order_by('-id').filter(name__id=idRef)[0]
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You make it a bit hard to tell what you're doing. The code simply checks if you get any rows from the query, by looking at the first element and catching the IndexError.

I would write it in a way that makes this intention much clearer:

```
for locationName in locationGroup:
    idRef = locationName.id
    rows = location.objects.order_by('-id').filter(name__id=idRef)
    if rows: # if we have rows do stuff otherwise continue
         element = rows[0]
         ...
```

In this case you can use [`get`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) which makes it even more clearer:

```
for locationName in locationGroup:
    idRef = locationName.id
    try:
         element = location.objects.get(name__id=idRef)
    except location.DoesNotExist:
         pass
```